# Electric and Magnetic Field

Tags: electric-fields, lenz-law

When an oscillatory current, I = Asin ωt is driven through the solenoid where A is the amplitude of the current, ω is the angular frequency and t is time, how do you find the expression for the electric field inside (r < R) the cylinder at time t?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume we are talking about an infinite solenoid. In that case, if we take a cylindrical coordinate system with the $\hat{z}$ direction along the solenoid axis, we have the coordinates $z$ and $\theta$ are cyclic because of the symmetries of the system and thus no quantity can depend on it.

[Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid#Infinite_continuous_solenoid) in Wikipedia you can find a derivation for the magnetic field inside the solenoid

$$
B = \mu_0 n i
$$

where $n$ is the number of turns for unit length, and $i$ is the current, in your case $i = A \sin (\omega t)$. The magnetic field is in the direction of the solenoid's axis $\hat{z}$, and is homogeneous.

As for the electric field it can be shown that the only non zero component is $E_\theta$, so $\vec{E} \equiv E_\theta(r) \hat\theta$. Here we can apply the Faraday's Law:

$$\oint\limits_{\partial A} \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = -\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\int \vec{B} \cdot d\vec{S}$$

$$\int\limits_0^{2\pi} E_\theta r d\theta = -\frac{d}{dt}\left(B \pi r^2 \right) = -\frac{d}{dt} \left( \mu_0 n i \pi r^2 \right) $$

$$2\pi E_\theta r = -\mu_0 n \pi r^2 A \omega \cos(\omega t)$$

and finally:

$$\vec{E} = -\frac{ \mu_0 n r}{2} A \omega \cos(\omega t) \hat{\theta}$$

$$\vec{B} = \mu_0 n A \sin{\omega t} \hat{z}$$

Comment: Great thanks! Just a doubt, shouldn't it be negative ∂/∂t?

Comment: @Phy07, yes it should! I'll edit the answer to fix it.